# Will cron run for different user or account?

Tags: cron

I'm new to cron. Someone just introduced it to me. Will cron run for different users?

I mean, I want to run a certain script (which update the database) every 5 minutes if the user is online. What if I have a lot of users who are online? Can cron handle a task like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `crontab -e` to edit the current user's crontab. However the script will have to check if the user is online or not.

Cron won't do that automatically.